# Stop Windows 10 Mobile activation

Tags: windows-10-mobile

I have a Windows 10 Mobile device. Since the OS is no longer supported by Microsoft, the activation servers are no longer online, yet the device keeps trying to activate itself. This is a problem because I still use the device as an alarm clock (and media player), and the alarm will not go off while the activation dialog is running. How can I force the device to not try to activate itself? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried keeping it in airplane mode?

Comment: I need to use Bluetooth though for my music. And sometimes a program will crash causing the phone to reboot and get stuck in the activation dialog. Airplane mode won't help here.

Comment: There's no such operating system as Windows 10 Phone. Did you mean Windows Phone 8 or Windows 10 Mobile?

Comment: The latter, thanks.